# How to Search & Navigate from the Same Textbox in VB.net Browser

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, browser, webbrowser-control, vb.net-2010

I am working on a web browser in Visual basic 2010 and I was wondering if there is any way I could search and navigate in the same textbox. I know it can be done because I have seen it done before but I do not know how to do it. If you are not sure what I am talking about, I am talking about typing something into the url bar that you want to search and hitting enter to search just like in chrome but also being able to type in a url and hit enter and go to that url. I already have the keydown event for the textbox and it is all set up to navigate but it don't search. What would be the best way to search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually found a better way to do this. The token was a good idea but it became easy to forget. The way I am doing it now:

```
Dim textArray = AddressBar.Text.Split(" ")
If (AddressBar.Text.Contains(".") AndAlso 
    Not AddressBar.Text.Contains(" ") AndAlso
    Not AddressBar.Text.Contains(" .") AndAlso
    Not AddressBar.Text.Contains(". ")) OrElse
    textArray(0).Contains(":/") OrElse textArray(0).Contains(":\") Then

  'We have an URL!
End If
```

As you can see this method checks for everything a normal URL could have in it and if it has those then the browser navigates but if it doesn't have those the browser searches google. I have yet to find anything that could be searched but the browser thinks is a URL. if you find something please let me know so I can work on fixing it.

Thanks Jeff Bridgman for your improved code.

Comment: If I copy/paste an URL in from another source but accidentally copy an extra space like `'www.google.com '`, I think this will try searching for it. Something solvable by trimming the input before checking all of this.

Comment: Yeah. I fixed that issue by just trimming the end before it does anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to somehow determine if what they typed looks like an URL or not, and if not, construct an different URL to navigate to that would take them to a search engine.

I'm tempted to recommend regex, but then you'd have [two problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html).

If it is acceptable, a better way to do it might be to have a search token. For example, you could check if the first character is a `?` and then use that as the trigger on whether to search of navigate.

```
? This will get searched
```

But unfortunately, that might be straight-forward to the user...

```
This won't search because I'm missing the '?'
```

Comment: I could do the search token it will just take a little bit to get used to. What would the code look like? `If TextBox1.Text.BeginsWith("?") then webbrowser.navigate("googlesearchqueryhere" + Textbox1.text) else webbrowser.navigate(textbox1.text)` I have never used the begins with function.

Comment: Yes, basically like that... you put a `.Trim()` on the the conditionaly if you want to handle if someone puts a space before the '?', and `String.Format()` might be super-handy if you need to inject the search value into the middle of a search url.

Comment: Okay, nevermind I figured that part out on the token. `if TextBox1.Text.StartsWith("?") then` but how do I make it remove the '?' after I do hit enter. Other than that it works great.

Comment: I went the easier way around with: `If TextBox1.Text.StartsWith("?") Then
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Remove(0, 1)
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com/#q=" + TextBox1.Text)
        Else
            WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
        End If` That works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a token, you might be better off letting .NET do the checking for you...

```
Try
   Dim uri = New Uri(txtAddressBar.Text)
   'Success? Then we have an URL!
Catch ex As UriFormatException
   'Not a valid URL, try searching instead...
End Try
```

Comment: I didn't know I could do that. But the results are not what I wanted. With this I would have to type "http://stackoverflow.com" instead of "stackoverflow.com" but otherwise, that would've been an awesome idea.

Comment: Hmm, I think formatting failed for you there... both URLs look the same.

Comment: Yea, sorry, I didn't test that one out that well. I was thinking that maybe you could get away with trying to concatenate "http://" onto the beginning, but then it validates URLs like "yahoo" so that's no good. Another option (but not a good one probably) is to just try to navigate to what they type in, if it fails, search. Or this may be one of the few times a regex is actually a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, You want them to scan for the url:

```
If ComboBox1.Text.StartsWith("www.") Or ComboBox1.Text.EndsWith(".com") Or ComboBox1.Text.EndsWith(".com.au") Or ComboBox1.Text.EndsWith(".uk") Or ComboBox1.Text.EndsWith(".weebly") Or ComboBox1.Text.EndsWith(".co") Or ComboBox1.Text.EndsWith(".nf") Or ComboBox1.Text.EndsWith(".sh") Then
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(ComboBox1.Text)
        CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate(ComboBox1.Text)
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(ComboBox1.Text)
    Else
        CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate("https://www.google.com.au/search?q=" & ComboBox1.Text)

    End If
```

Comment: Here is help: This is how you do it, remade so easier:

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, You want them to scan for the url:

 `If ComboBox1.Text.StartsWith("www.") Or ComboBox1.Text.EndsWith(".com") Or ComboBox1.Text.EndsWith(".com.au") Or ComboBox1.Text.EndsWith(".uk") Or ComboBox1.Text.EndsWith(".weebly") Or ComboBox1.Text.EndsWith(".co") Or ComboBox1.Text.EndsWith(".nf") Or ComboBox1.Text.EndsWith(".sh") Then
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(ComboBox1.Text)
            CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate(ComboBox1.Text)
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(ComboBox1.Text)
        Else
            CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate("https://www.google.com.au/search?q=" & ComboBox1.Text)`

```
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for a textbox (i changed it a little bit so it worked with textbox instead of combobox)

```
    If Textbox1.Text.StartsWith("www.") Or Textbox1.Text.EndsWith(".com") Or 
    Textbox1.Text.EndsWith(".com.au") Or Textbox1.Text.EndsWith(".uk") Or 
    Textbox1.Text.EndsWith(".weebly") Or Textbox1.Text.EndsWith(".co") Or 
    Textbox1.Text.EndsWith(".nf") Or Textbox1.Text.EndsWith(".nl") Or 
    Textbox1.Text.EndsWith(".net") Or Textbox1.Text.EndsWith(".eu") Or 
    Textbox1.Text.EndsWith(".tk") Or Textbox1.Text.EndsWith(".sh") Then
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)

    Else
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com.au/search?q=" & TextBox1.Text)
    End If
```